# Why Mysql's Group By and Oracle's Group by behaviours are different

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

Why Mysql's Group By and Oracle's Group by behaviours are different

I found many times that Mysql's groupBy functionality and Oracle's GroupBy funcnality are behaving different

Many times I found error in Oracle(which is actually wrong query) but Mysql will give result in to this

so is there any reason behind this Mysql weird behavior

Comment: they are just diferent implementation of "sql" and they can do "what ever they whant" (sorry for bad english)

Comment: We need some examples to understand what you are referring to. you can use SQL Fiddle to prepare examples.

Comment: @AnupShah I know this behavior, and I seen lots of example for this but I am not understanding that does they have maintain any standards or what , because in Mysql and Oracle are different but in Oracle and SQLSERVER they are same

Comment: @Melon If you are not knowing answer then its okey I am not bothering you but let me know what is actual reson behind this does they follow any standards or what

Comment: You have to consider that Syntax is different between PL-SQL, MySQL and T-SQL, but usage for `Group By` Clause is the same.

Comment: @SaUce yes sir Group-By usage is same we can not use groupBy without using of Aggregate function then why MySql Allowing it? and why it is not using standards Like Oracle and SQLserver as well as Sybase?

Comment: That is how MySQL developers decided to implement it, you can't say it is wrong or it is right just because other DBMS do it.

Comment: @ChintanGor i dont realy know the answer, sorry. i just whanted to say that they are diferent implementation of the standar sql: you can check de diferences [here](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The MySQL designers put in their nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY` in an attempt to make development easier and certain queries more efficient.

Here's their rationale.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

There is a server mode called `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` which disables the nonstandard extensions. You can set this mode using this statement.

```
 SET SESSION SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'
```

Here's a quote from that page, with emphasis added.

> If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of `GROUP BY` permits the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns... In this case, the server is **free to choose any value from each group**, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are **nondeterministic**, which is probably not what you want.

The important word here is **nondeterministic.**  What does that mean?  It means  *random, but worse.* If the server chose random values, that implies it would return different values in different queries, so you have a chance of catching the problem when you test your software. But *nondeterministic* in this context means the server chooses the same value every time, *until it doesn't.*

Why might it change the value it chooses? A server upgrade is one reason. A change to table size might be another. The point is, the server is free to return whatever value it wants.

I wish people newly learning SQL would set this `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode; they'd get much more predictable results from their queries, and the server would reject nondeterministic queries.

Comment: MySQL also provides an aggregate function `ANY_VALUE`, which has the same effect as running without 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'

Answer (score 9):

Oracle does not extend the older SQL Standard that states that all items in the select list not contained in an aggregate function must be included in the group by clause.

The [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) state:

---

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL because the name column in the select list does not appear in the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
  FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
  WHERE o.custid = c.custid
  GROUP BY o.custid;
```

> For the query to be legal, the name column must be omitted from the select list or named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

---

So to answer your question as to why MySQL does this the most pertinent extract is:

> You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

I always advocate to steer clear of this particular MySQL extension unless you fully understand it.

Imagine the following simple table (T):

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |
----|---------+----------|
1   |    A    |    X     |
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

In MySQL you can write

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY Column1;
```

This actually breaks the SQL Standard, but it works in MySQL, however the trouble is it is non-deterministic, the result:

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |
----|---------+----------|
1   |    A    |    X     |
```

Is no more or less correct than

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |  
----|---------+----------|
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

So what you are saying is give me one row for each distinct value of `Column1`, which both results sets satisfy, so how do you know which one you will get? Well you don't, it seems to be a fairly popular misconception that you can add and `ORDER BY` clause to influence the results, so for example the following query:

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY Column1
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Would ensure that you get the following result:

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |  
----|---------+----------|
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

because of the `ORDER BY ID DESC`, however this is not true ([as demonstrated here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b917/1)).

The [MySQL documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) state:

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

So even though you have an order by this does not apply until after one row per group has been selected, and this one row is non-determistic.

The SQL-Standard does allow columns in the select list not contained in the GROUP BY or an aggregate function, however these columns must be functionally dependant on a column in the GROUP BY. From the SQL-2003-Standard:

> 15) If T is a grouped table, then let G be the set of grouping columns of T. In each  contained
>   in  , each column reference that references a column of T shall reference some column C that
>   is functionally dependent on G or shall be contained in an aggregated argument of a 
>   whose aggregation query is QS.

For example, ID in the sample table is the PRIMARY KEY, so we know it is unique in the table, so the following query conforms to the SQL standard and would run in MySQL and fail in many DBMS currently (At the time of writing Postgresql is the closest DBMS I know of to correctly implementing the standard - [Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4a6a4/1)):

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY ID;
```

Since ID is unique for each row, there can only be one value of `Column1` for each ID, one value of `Column2` there is no ambiguity about what to return for each row.

Answer (score 3):

`group by` is a very well defined SQL construct.  To the best of my knowledge, almost all databases will treat equivalent SQL queries the same.

I can think of two differences that might arise when comparing results from Oracle and MySQL.

The first is that Oracle treats empty strings and `NULL` values as the same.  So the following query in Oracle:

```
select c, count(*)
from (select '' as c from dual union all
      select NULL from dual
     ) t
group by c;
```

will return one row with a count of "2".  Every other database (almost every other?) follows the ANSI-standard and would return two rows with a count of 1.

The second difference is that MySQL extends the standard to allow non-aggregated columns in the select.  So, MySQL will allow this:

```
select a, b
from t
group by a;
```

This generates a syntax error in almost every other database.  And, if `a` is not a unique column in `t`, then this behavior violates the ANSI standard.  If you are encountering a syntax error, this is probably what you are stumbling upon.  Oracle is probably doing the right thing in this case, and you should learn to write better aggregation queries.

Another difference is the ordering of results in a `group by`.  MySQL has deprecated this feature, so no code should actually depend on it any more.  However, result sets are inherently unordered, unless there is a specific `order by` clause, so two result sets in different orders would be equivalent.