# SQL to return first recorded date from All-time Records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Fishing Database that stores All-time records. However, when someone has a joint record, I want to revert to the first capture as the true record.

```
select * 
from T 
inner join (select Type, 
                   Name, 
                   max(TotDrams) as maxdrams 
            from T 
            WHERE Type='Common Bream' 
            group by Type, Name 
           ) sq on T.Type = sq.Type 
                and T.Name = sq.Name 
                and sq.maxdrams = T.TotDrams 
ORDER BY Ranking ASC
```

The above returns the all time records with the best capture for each name, but when a record is joint it naturally returns the additional record. I only want the earliest date record to be included in the all time records.

Is there a way of adapting the above code to remove the additional joint records and only pick the earliest recorded?

```
Fishname     Rank            Weight           Angler            Date

Slimey       Rank 1        2 lb   3 oz      John Budd         30/11/2013
Fishy        Rank 2        1 lb   15 oz     Chris Clot        12/01/2009
Scales       Rank 3        1 lb   12 oz     John Budd         21/03/2014
Scales       Rank 3        1 lb   12 oz     Harry White       01/04/2002
```

With the above example - which is what is currently happening, I would like to have John Budd's joint record removed as it is joint and is not the original.

One other note:- This SQL will be used with php.

Comment: Does T have an ID column?

Comment: can you give sample data for the tables?

Comment: No Raj it doesn't. I have a SQL Fiddle set up. Different fields names but same end result. Records with zero entries also produce this issue but I have a plan for them. If you look at the result and see that rank 2 has three people with the same record - the perfect issue :)  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d09cd/1

Comment: can you explain why john budd gets removed? is it because you only want the winning fish he caught so like one record per person? or another criteria?

Comment: Well it is for being a little tidy. The record table also shows a neat list of the target fish. Now I want John removed from the all-time because he needs to actually beat the record in order to take the spot. No room for joints.

Comment: Two questions - **1.** Why is `DateCaught` a `VARCHAR`? This should surely be a `DATE`? **2.** In your example, there are [4 records for the (Species, Fishname) tuple of  (Common Bream, The Lid)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d09cd/36) - all of these have a `TotalDrams` value of 0, and a `DateCaught` of `''` (Blank) - which of these 4 should be returned?

Comment: so just add a MIN(date) on your innerjoin select and include it in the ON conditiion

Comment: This data set is in need of normalization.

Comment: DateCaught is entered from a website form that is probably the reason it being VARCHAR. The zero scores for the TotalDrams mean they haven't been caught yet. When a new angler joins, all target fish for that angler are entered into the table and reset to 0. Bit like having a checklist when you first start collecting something.

Comment: Might be onto something... Is it possible to min(DateCaught) but converting it first within the SQL statement??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this is slightly different, rather than trying to limit the results to the maximum, I would exclude the results that aren't. So using something like:

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    T
        LEFT JOIN T AS T2
            ON T2.Species = T.Species
            AND T2.FishName = T.FishName
            AND (T2.TotalDrams < T.TotalDrams
                OR (T.TotalDrams = T2.TotalDrams AND T2.DateCaught > T.DateCaught))
WHERE   T.Species = 'Common Bream'
AND     T2.Species IS NULL
ORDER BY T.Rank ASC;
```

This uses the standard `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` approach to exclude records where they are for the same fish type and either:

- Have a lower value for `TotalDrams`

**OR**

- Have the same value for `TotalDrams` **AND** a later `DateCaught`

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d09cd/34)**

Due to the way MySQL materialises sub-queries you might also find that this performs better than the original query that didn't give the required results!

---

**EDIT**

Okay, new approach. I think the best way to go about this is using variables to store a new Row number for each record, then you can filter for the top 1. The following will assign your row number based on ordering criteria:

```
SELECT  @r:= CASE WHEN @f = t.FishName AND @s:= t.Species 
                    THEN @r + 1 
                ELSE 1 
            END AS RowNum,
        @f:= t.FishName AS FishName,
        @s:= t.Species AS Species,
        t.Rank,
        t.Pounds,
        t.Ounces,
        t.Drams,
        t.TotalDrams,
        t.Peg,
        t.Angler,
        STR_TO_DATE(IF(t.DateCaught = '', '31/12/2050', t.DateCaught), '%d/%m/%Y')  AS DateCaught
FROM    T
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT  @f:= '',@s:='', @r:= 0) AS v
ORDER BY t.FishName, t.Species, t.TotalDrams DESC, DateCaught ASC;
```

Then you can put this into a subquery, and limit the records to the top 1:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  @r:= CASE WHEN @f = t.FishName AND @s = t.Species 
                                THEN @r + 1 
                            ELSE 1 
                        END AS RowNum,
                    @f:= t.FishName AS FishName,
                    @s:= t.Species AS Species,
                    t.Rank,
                    t.Pounds,
                    t.Ounces,
                    t.Drams,
                    t.TotalDrams,
                    t.Peg,
                    t.Angler,
                    t.DateCaught
            FROM    T
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT  @f:= '',@s:='', @r:= 0) AS v
            ORDER BY t.FishName, t.Species, t.TotalDrams DESC, STR_TO_DATE(IF(t.DateCaught = '', '31/12/2050', t.DateCaught), '%d/%m/%Y') ASC
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY t.Rank ASC;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db0c8/37)**

This is the most flexible approach, if you want to add more rules, i.e. if you have two the same weight, and on the same date, you can add further ordering to your subquery, e.g. `Angler`. This guarantees only one record for each tuple of (fishname, species), and deterministic results given enough ordering.

Comment: only issue with this is empty dates are considered smaller than ones with dates..

Comment: Yes, I noticed this, but the data is seriously flawed. Since dates are stored as VARCHARs it also treats '30/11/2013' as being after '21/03/2014'. In the absence of any detail in the question about how to deal with empty dates, MySQL's logic of treating empty dates as earlier seemed as good a logic as any to go with.

Comment: Yup thats why i posted an answer with a conversion for the dates method so the op can try and use it.. It really does need normalization though

Comment: GarethD - Thank you. Absolutely brilliant. Well happy now. And a big thanks for everyone else and their time.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another join to the earliest dates that each fish was caught. Something like:

```
select * 
from T 
inner join (select Species, 
                   FishName, 
                   max(TotalDrams) as maxdrams 
            from T 
            WHERE Species='Common Bream' 
            AND DateCaught <> ''
            group by Species, FishName 
           ) sq on T.Species = sq.Species 
                and T.FishName = sq.FishName 
                and sq.maxdrams = T.TotalDrams 
inner join (select Species, 
                   FishName, 
                   min(DateCaught) as minDate 
            from T 
            WHERE Species='Common Bream' 
            AND DateCaught <> ''
            group by Species, FishName 
           ) sq2 on T.Species = sq2.Species 
                and T.FishName = sq2.FishName 
                and sq2.minDate = T.DateCaught 
where T.DateCaught <> ''
ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

And following on from that, you could refactor the 2 criteria into a single join:

```
select * 
from T 
inner join (select Species, 
                   FishName, 
                   max(TotalDrams) as maxdrams,
                   min(DateCaught) as minDate 
            from T 
            WHERE Species='Common Bream' 
            AND DateCaught <> ''
            group by Species, FishName 
           ) sq on T.Species = sq.Species 
                and T.FishName = sq.FishName 
                and sq.maxdrams = T.TotalDrams 
                and sq.minDate = T.DateCaught 
where T.DateCaught <> ''
ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

EDIT:

Further analysis of the data structure shows that the answer above isn't quite right - it's filtering out several records because of the date being a varchar, and also an incorrect assumption about the data structure.. Revised answer below:

```
select distinct 
   T.species,
   t.fishname,
   t.rank,
   t.pounds,
   t.ounces,
   t.drams,
   t.totaldrams,
   t.peg,
   t.angler,
   sq.*,
   sq2.*
FROM (select Species, 
             FishName, 
              max(TotalDrams) as maxdrams
      from T 
      WHERE Species='Common Bream' 
      group by Species, FishName 
     ) sq 
inner join (select Species, 
                   FishName, 
                   TotalDrams,
                   min(if(DateCaught='',STR_TO_DATE('31/12/3099','%d/%m/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(DateCaught,'%d/%m/%Y'))) as minDate 
            from T 
            WHERE Species='Common Bream' 
            group by Species, FishName, TotalDrams 
           ) sq2 on sq.Species = sq2.Species 
                 and sq.FishName = sq2.FishName 
                 and sq.MaxDrams = sq2.TotalDrams
inner join T on sq.species = T.species 
and sq.fishname = T.fishname
and sq.maxdrams = T.totaldrams
and sq2.mindate = if(DateCaught='',STR_TO_DATE('31/12/3099','%d/%m/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(DateCaught,'%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: why do you have two inner joins... cant you just do the min date inside the first innerjoin?? +1 though

Comment: [**SEE HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d09cd/39) they have the same results and the query is much cleaner without the second inner join :)

Comment: This sql seems to return only some. There are 25 different Common Bream with different names.

Comment: Hi.. you're right.. I spent a little more time on it, and a couple of assumptions I had made were incorrect. Couple that with the date being in a varchar, and the results weren't quite right. The revised answer should work, although it will give you dupes for the fish that have never been caught..

Comment: @JohnRuddell - I did need the second join after all! the grouping is different when looking for the min date!

Comment: This is by far the best edit from StevieG. Sorry but I'm being fussy now :) Is there a possible way to limit a record - such as The Lid in this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31da10/1 to 1 row (doesn't matter which) and how would be best to sort by rank in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Sort by date after ranking, then group by fish name. Looks like that works?

`select * from T 
inner join (select Species, FishName, max(TotalDrams) as maxdrams from T 
WHERE Species='Common Bream' group by Species, FishName 
) sq on T.Species = sq.Species and T.FishName = sq.FishName and sq.maxdrams = T.TotalDrams 
GROUP BY T.FishName ORDER BY Rank, DateCaught ASC`

Comment: This is good. One small issue, and it would be the DateCaught. The is not sorting and I assume this is because it is a string?

Comment: What isn't sorting properly? That column being a varchar will likely be problematic.

Comment: Confusion with my php stuff! Okay it works beautifully but with one small annoyance being that the earliest DateCaught is not being picked. Should be Weezy G in 2009. I've update the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a87dd/2

Comment: This is not deterministic - By using `GROUP BY T.FishName` you are telling MySQL that you want one row for each value of `fishname`, **however**, the columns you specify in the `ORDER BY` do not determine which values for fields not included in the `GROUP BY` are chosen. If you are using `GROUP BY` properly, there will only be one value to chose from, if not then a value is chosen at random from the available values, and these random values are then sorted according your order by. This is well documented behaviour and queries like this should not be relied on.

Comment: I have explained in much more detail in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21680021/1048425) the shortcomings of this extension when not used properly.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely not the right way to go. I was hoping there was a simple solution.

Comment: I have updated the SQL fiddle with less records using the above SQL. So it should now be only six fish now. This is the closest but issue is still a shared record where it does not pull out the earliest record. Record 2 rank Waddle should be Weezy G as the angler. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db0c8/1