# I want to display data from multiple rows from database into one column in html table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 4 tables

1. patient card,this includes all basic details of patient.
2. patient card 2,this includes patients complaints about 
                   this health,disease,and prescription(medicines) given by 
                   doctor.
3. disease,this includes disease of patients.
4. medicines,this includes medicines given to patients.

Now what i want is to display all the field from patient card 1,patient card 2 and all the disease and medicines from disease and medicine tables for one particular patient.For example:patient abc can have multiple disease and medicines in disease and medicines table.

I am using the below query using group_concat  data is displayed in html table in coma separated way but issue is data is being displayed multiple times

```
$this->db->select('p1.*,p2.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(dis.disease_type SEPARATOR ",") as disease_type,
        GROUP_CONCAT(med.medicines SEPARATOR ",") as medicines', FALSE);       
$this->db->from('patientcard1 p1');

$this->db->join('patientcard2 p2','p2.card_id = p1.card_id','left');
$this->db->join('pdisease pd','pd.card_id1 = p2.card_id1','left');
$this->db->join('pmedicines pm','pm.card_id1 = p2.card_id','left');
$this->db->join('disease dis','dis.disease_id = pd.disease_id','left');
$this->db->join('medicines med','med.medicine_id = pm.medicines','left');
$this->db->group_by('u.unit_id');
$patient_details=$this->db->get();
return $patient_details;
```

Comment: You could try using `distinct` within the `group_concat` which may address some symptoms, but you are joining 6 tables, but only grouping by one column, this is a peculiarity of MySQL that leads to big misunderstandings of how to form good summary queries.

Comment: I suggest you read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21680037/2067753 which briefly describes the non-standard way MySQL approaches group by queries. The results can be random or misleading and unless you really understand the way this works, for a health application, I would be very hesitant to use that approach. Research the option `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`