# Getting MYSQL error with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in MySql Godaddy VPS Cpanel

Tags: mysql

Hi i am using PHPMYAdmin MYSQL in godaddy-vps server while using it i am getting an error when executing my SQL Query

I want total count of likes.post_id in likes table based on posts.user_id=2 posts list, by joining two table by likes.post_id=posts.id where likes_status='true'

```
SELECT likes.post_id, likes.like_status, P.id, P.user_id, 
  count(*) AS likeCountProfilePosts  FROM likes 
  INNER JOIN posts AS P ON P.id=likes.post_id  
  WHERE P.id IN (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE posts.user_id =2) 
  AND likes.like_status='true'
```

Getting error :

> #1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'howtags_social_db.likes.post_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

If anyone know the solution please tell me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Mysql's Group By and Oracle's Group by behaviours are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679804/why-mysqls-group-by-and-oracles-group-by-behaviours-are-different)

Comment: You are using `count` without a `group by` so all results will be returned as one, likely you want `group by likes.post_id, likes.like_status, P.id, P.user_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, 
 1. Open godaddy panel
 2. Open phpmyadmin
 3. Open Variable Setting
[image]

4. Search MySQL mode
5. Delete Only Full Group By on MySQL mode variables
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my SQL query and its working fine for me instead of changing PHPMyAdmin settings

```
 SELECT comments.post_id,  
  count(*) AS commentCount FROM comments  
  INNER JOIN posts AS P on P.id=comments.post_id  
  GROUP BY comments.post_id  
  ORDER BY comments.post_id DESC
```