# Laravel Eloquent/DB select top 1 Row Per Group

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I have a SQL Query in my controller, It fetches all data from a table to sort it by date. There are some duplicate entries of sku_parent in table with different id, I want to fetch the latest entry of each sku_parent according to 'date'. This is my DB:

```sql
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | warehouse | sku_parent | sku_child | case_balance |    date    |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  5 | SeaWest   |        120 | 120 - 25  |          400 | 2020-08-26 | 2020-08-26 19:02:20 | 2020-08-26 19:02:20 |
|  6 | SeaWest   |        121 | 121 - 25  |          784 | 2020-08-26 | 2020-08-26 19:02:42 | 2020-08-26 19:02:42 |
|  7 | SeaWest   |        121 | 121 - 25  |          734 | 2020-08-26 | 2020-08-26 19:03:46 | 2020-08-26 19:03:46 |
|  8 | SeaWest   |        120 | 120 - 25  |          350 | 2020-08-26 | 2020-08-26 19:03:46 | 2020-08-26 19:03:46 |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This is what I have done so far:

```php
    $data = DB::table('logs')
           ->where('sku_parent', $request->sku)
           ->where('id', \DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from logs)"))
           ->whereBetween('date', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
           ->get();
```

This code only fetches the max id from table and does not shows other product name. I want to get each product name having the max id.

Comment: By works presumably you mean just returns two rows, because it is not returning sensible data. Your first row shows an ID of 8, and a case_balance of 400, but the case_balance for the row with the id of 8 is in fact 350. Your question remains valid, i.e. how do I get the top 1 per group in laravel (which I don't know, I have never used it), but you definitely should not be trying to recreate that query. I've previously [explained with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21680021/1048425) why (unless you know what you are doing) you should avoid this MySQL extension of the group by clause

Comment: thanks for mentioning that, i won't use that query, any way to get the data I want btw?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: working on php my admin 7.4.7

Comment: I think the following query would work for you: `SELECT ID, sku_parent, sku_child, case_balance , date , created_at, updated_at FROM logs WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM logs GROUP BY sku_parent)`, as I say though, I have no experience of Laravel, so can't translate this for you. The general principal would be to get the [top 1 per group](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Laravel+top+1+per+group), so there may be answers based on that search?

Comment: yes, the query is working fine, now just need to implement this in laravel :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching `MAX id` of an item, you can group them all by the `sku_parent` first, and only take the latest records that have duplicate values with [havingRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods). Try something like this:

```
$data = DB::table('logs')
       ->where('sku_parent', $request->sku)
       ->groupBy('sku_parent')
       ->havingRaw('count('sku_parent') > 1')
       ->whereBetween('date', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
       ->latest()
       ->get();
```

*PS: Haven't tested it, but should give the desired result. Hit me up if any errors pop up, or if isn't what you wanted.*

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'sku_parent' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Answer (score 0):

To pick a latest row per group (sku_parent) you can do self join like

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE logs
    (`id` int, `warehouse` varchar(7), `sku_parent` int, `sku_child` varchar(8), `case_balance` int, `date` datetime, `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO logs
    (`id`, `warehouse`, `sku_parent`, `sku_child`, `case_balance`, `date`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
    (5, 'SeaWest', 120, '120 - 25', 400, '2020-08-26 00:00:00', '2020-08-26 19:02:20', '2020-08-26 19:02:20'),
    (6, 'SeaWest', 121, '121 - 25', 784, '2020-08-26 00:00:00', '2020-08-26 19:02:42', '2020-08-26 19:02:42'),
    (7, 'SeaWest', 121, '121 - 25', 734, '2020-08-26 00:00:00', '2020-08-26 19:03:46', '2020-08-26 19:03:46'),
    (8, 'SeaWest', 120, '120 - 25', 350, '2020-08-26 00:00:00', '2020-08-26 19:03:46', '2020-08-26 19:03:46')
;
```

Query

```
select a.*
from logs a
left join logs b on a.sku_parent = b.sku_parent
    and a.id < b.id
where b.sku_parent is null
    and a.sku_parent = :sku_parent
    and a.date between :from_date and :to_date
```

Query Builder

```
DB::table('logs as a')
  ->select('a.*')
  ->leftJoin('logs as b', function ($join) {
        $join->on('a.sku_parent', '=', 'b.sku_parent')
             ->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.id < b.id'));
   })
  ->whereNull('b.sku_parent')
  ->where('a.sku_parent', $request->sku)
  ->whereBetween('a.date', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
  ->get();
```

If you need to pick the latest record base on `created_at` then change the `leftJoin` part to `->whereRaw(DB::raw('a.created_at < b.created_at'))`

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84c45c/2)

[Laravel Eloquent select all rows with max created_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959102/laravel-eloquent-select-all-rows-with-max-created-at/47959128#47959128)