# What makes these two SQL queries different? Stumping me completely

Tags: sql, mysql

this is my first post on stack overflow, so excuse any ignorance of posting etiquette or whatnot. I was working on this [leetcode SQL puzzle](https://leetcode.com/problems/immediate-food-delivery-ii/description/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-sql-50), and am very confused as to why these two queries give differing results. They seem near identical to me? Is the presence of `customer_pref_delivery_date` in the common-table expression somehow throwing off the first query?

I am using MySQL.

Problematic query:

```
WITH first_orders AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        MIN(order_date) AS order_date,
        customer_pref_delivery_date
    FROM Delivery
    GROUP BY customer_id
)
SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(IF(order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date, 1, 0)) / COUNT(*) * 100, 2) AS immediate_percentage
FROM first_orders
```

Correct query:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(SUM(IF(order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date, 1, 0)) / COUNT(*) * 100, 2) AS immediate_percentage
FROM Delivery
WHERE (customer_id, order_date) IN (
    SELECT 
        customer_id,
        min(order_date)
    FROM Delivery
    GROUP BY customer_id
)
```

Comment: strongly encourage you to enable sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY; this has been a default since mysql 5.7.5.  it will help keep you from making mistakes like this.

Comment: Why would such different queries return the same result?!?

Comment: This query runs in an obsolete version of MySQL. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

The first query is wrong because you're including a column that is neither part of an aggregate function, or part of the group by (either directly or via functional dependency). This is effectively:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    MIN(order_date) AS order_date,
    ANY(customer_pref_delivery_date) AS customer_pref_delivery_date
FROM Delivery
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Where `ANY()` does exactly what it says on in the tin, it will retrieve any value from all available rows. So with a really simple sample data set:

| id | customer_id | order_date | customer_pref_delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-02-02 | 2024-02-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-01 |

When you run your query you might expect to get the value for `customer_pref_delivery_date` that corresponds to your order date returned by `MIN(order_date)` but that is not guaranteed. [An example of this is on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ADBSHf1) where the result is:

| customer_id | order_date | customer_pref_delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-05 |

So it has taken the correct minimum order from row with id 2, but has taken any value of `customer_pref_delivery_date` and that happens to be from row with id 1.

So even though the first order actually does have a preferred delivery date that matches the order date, your query has brought back a mis-match of data and is giving incorrect results.

As noted in the comments, the SQL Standard does actually allow columns to be used in the select if not in the group by (I touch upon this with an example at the end of [this answer on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21680021/1048425)). Effectively what this means is that if the result of the pseduo function `ANY()` is guaranteed to be deterministic due to database constraints (Primary key, unique key etc) then it is not necessary to include the additional column. If you are very comfortable with your understanding of the implementation then I would say go ahead and take advantage of it and omit columns, but if you are unsure at all then don't. The benefits of not typing an extra few words don't outweigh the risks of incorrect results.

The best way of sorting this is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get your first order, this then gives you access to all columns associated with that order, e.g.

```
WITH RankedOrders AS
(   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) AS RowNum
    FROM Delivery
)
SELECT id, customer_id, order_date, customer_pref_delivery_date
FROM RankedOrders AS rd
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

This returns the first order per customer but ensures the delivery date corresponds with the first order:

| id | customer_id | order_date | customer_pref_delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-01 |

You can then extend this to include your aggregation of orders:

```
WITH RankedOrders AS
(   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) AS RowNum
    FROM Delivery
)
SELECT ROUND(SUM(IF(order_date = customer_pref_delivery_date, 1, 0)) / COUNT(*) * 100, 2) AS immediate_percentage
FROM RankedOrders AS rd
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/adKFGB_A)**

Comment: I see... I had a feeling something like that was the case. My knowledge of window functions is not the best so I better go practice those. Thank you so much!

Comment: There is a concept called functional dependency that allows the otherwise-ambiguous group by when the primary key is also included, but may databases don't support it, it's frowned upon using it even when it is, and poorly-enforced over the years for mysql. See here, for example: https://blog.jooq.org/functional-dependencies-in-sql-group-by/

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the first query to be far more efficient.

Both samples have this basic inner query to find the first order per customer:

```
SELECT customer_id,
    min(order_date)
FROM Delivery
GROUP BY customer_id
```

The first sample also includes the `customer_pref_delivery_date` at this level. Technically, you should probably also group by this column, and most other databases would actually force you to do this (MySQL is kind of bad here). But the advantage is it lets you include that value as part of the initial pass through the data, and so the first query is able to effectively do this all at once.

The second query looks through the original data and uses the inner/nested query for matching. In effect, it requires an additional pass through the source data, with a matching operation from the subquery at each step.

---

If it were me, I'd consolidate the first query to one level, as well as fix the grouping and otherwise use more standards-compliant options:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    ROUND(SUM(case when min(order_date) = customer_pref_delivery_date then 1 else 0 end) / COUNT(*) * 100, 2) AS immediate_percentage
FROM Delivery
GROUP BY customer_id, customer_pref_delivery_date
```